# Changing style of label boxes in TimelinePlot

Tags: plotting

When I export the below `TimelinePlot` to an .eps figure (to include in a document), the boundaries of the rounded boxes surrounding the label text do not appear.  (They appear in the below .bmp file, however.)  Thus I would like to increase their thickness, in hopes they'll appear in the .eps file.

I can change the *indicator lines* (through `PlotStyle -> {{AbsoluteThickness[4], Orange}, {AbsoluteThickness[4], Green}}`) but not the boundaries of the rounded boxes themselves.

How do I increase the thickness or otherwise change the style of the surrounding boxes?

Using `Framed` around the text gives an inappropriate box *within* the indicator box.

```
TimelinePlot[
 {
  {Labeled[Interval[{{2017, 1, 1}, {2017, 1, 15}}], "Begin"],
   Labeled[Interval[{{2018, 1, 1}, {2019, 1, 1}}], "Middle"]},

  {Labeled[{2017, 1, 1}, "Project begins"],
   Labeled[{2017, 4, 1}, "xxx"],
   Labeled[{2017, 7, 1}, "yyy"],
   Labeled[{2017, 10, 1}, "zzz"],
   Labeled[{2018, 1, 1}, "Midterm review"],
   Labeled[{2018, 4, 1}, "www"],
   Labeled[{2018, 7, 1}, "rrr"],
   Labeled[{2018, 10, 1}, "sss"],
   Labeled[{2019, 1, 1}, "Overall\n project\n review"]}

  },
 PlotRange -> {{{2017, 1, 1}, {2019, 1, 1}}},
 GridLines -> {DateRange["2017", "2019", Quantity[3, "Months"]], None},
 GridLinesStyle -> {{Dashed, Gray}, None},
 PlotStyle -> {{AbsoluteThickness[4], Orange}, {AbsoluteThickness[4], 
    Green}},
 Spacings -> {10, 10},
 FrameStyle -> {18, {18, Italic}},
 FillingStyle -> Opacity[0.3],
 Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"Tasks", "Payable milestones"}, Bottom],
 ImageSize -> 700,
 AspectRatio -> .2,
 Background -> LightYellow]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inspection of the `InputForm` of the generated plot reveals that a function is used to generate the labeling rectangles:

```
DisplayFunction :> (FormBox[
    FrameBox[
     StyleBox[
      StyleBox[
       PaneBox[#1, Alignment -> Left, AppearanceElements -> None, 
        ImageSizeAction -> "ResizeToFit"], LineIndent -> 0, 
       StripOnInput -> False], {FontFamily -> "Arial"}, 
      StripOnInput -> False], Background -> GrayLevel[1], 
     RoundingRadius -> 5, ContentPadding -> True, 
     FrameMargins -> {{5, 5}, {5, 5}}, FrameStyle -> Thickness[0.01], 
     StripOnInput -> False], TraditionalForm] & )
```

The interesting bit is `FrameStyle -> Thickness[0.01]`. This doesn't appear anywhere else in the generated code, so it's a prime candidate for replacement.

As it happens, a `Thickness` of 0.01 is far too low in this context: compare e.g. the following:

```
Labeled["sample", "label", Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Thickness[#]] & /@ {0.01, 0.1, 1, 3, 5}
```

[image: examples]

The first three cases are essentially the same. The front end will display the thinnest line it *can* display probably, but exporting won't work.

Coming back to your plot, you can then change the thickness of those frames after the fact using a replacement rule:

```
yourplot /. HoldPattern[FrameStyle -> Thickness[0.01]] -> (FrameStyle -> Thickness[5])
```

[image: exaggerated]

This was a bit exaggerated for effect. You will want to scale the new thickness down to your liking. I exported this both to PDF and EPS with success.

Comment: Thanks!  a non-obvious solution.

Comment: @MarcoB nice 'looking under the hood' +1:)