# Replacement Rule Line Thickness

Tags: plotting, replacement

I have a plot with imported data that I have used a replacement rule to make the data a line rather than individual points. However, I want to increase the thickness of that line. How do I do this? I have tried looking at [Changing style of label boxes in TimelinePlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115953/changing-style-of-label-boxes-in-timelineplot/115963#115963) for an example of changing the line thickness but it is different than what I want to do. Here is what I have:

```
Show[ListPointPlot3D[Sidata1[[1 ;; 59, 3 ;; 5]], PlotStyle -> {Red}, PlotRange -> All],
  ListPointPlot3D[Sidata1[[60 ;; 89, 3 ;; 5]], PlotStyle -> {Gray}, PlotRange -> All],
  ListPointPlot3D[Sidata1[[90 ;; 110, 3 ;; 5]], PlotStyle -> {Red}, PlotRange -> All],
  ListPointPlot3D[Sidata1[[111 ;; 141, 3 ;; 5]], PlotStyle -> {Gray}, PlotRange -> All],
  ListPointPlot3D[Sidata1[[142 ;; 201, 3 ;; 5]], PlotStyle -> {Red}, PlotRange -> All], 
  AxesLabel -> {"q", "s2", "alpha"}, LabelStyle -> {16}, PlotLabel -> None, ViewPoint -> {.5, -2, 1}, 
  AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, 16], BoxStyle -> Directive[Black], TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 16], 
  AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {-1, -1}}, ImageSize -> Large] /. Point -> Line
```

I've tried increasing the line thickness at the end of the input with this code that does not work:

```
/. Point -> Line[PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.1]]
```

Here is my data:

```
{{0, 0.00586554, 1.85613, 4.76551*10^-28, 5.26926}, {1, 0.00586038, 
  1.85857, 0.00496208, 5.26553}, {2, 0.00583292, 1.86694, 0.00737286, 
  5.28264}, {3, 0.00578611, 1.88105, 0.00995626, 5.31438}, {4, 
  0.00572788, 1.90041, 0.0195179, 5.34518}, {5, 0.0056491, 1.92576, 
  0.026371, 5.3971}, {6, 0.00555664, 1.95654, 0.0357567, 5.4579}, {7, 
  0.005454, 1.99256, 0.0488175, 5.52469}, {8, 0.00533414, 2.03443, 
  0.0587529, 5.61315}, {9, 0.00520924, 2.08121, 0.0728039, 
  5.70511}, {10, 0.00507624, 2.13333, 0.0868532, 5.80991}, {11, 
  0.00493048, 2.19114, 0.0969574, 5.937}, {12, 0.00479085, 2.25265, 
  0.111276, 6.06199}, {13, 0.00464483, 2.31891, 0.12169, 
  6.20612}, {14, 0.00449348, 2.3895, 0.12767, 6.36945}, {15, 
  0.00435635, 2.46022, 0.134399, 6.52873}, {16, 0.00421573, 2.53408, 
  0.13467, 6.70861}, {17, 0.00408066, 2.60798, 0.130038, 
  6.89764}, {18, 0.003962, 2.67731, 0.122165, 7.08088}, {19, 
  0.0038446, 2.74659, 0.107359, 7.27855}, {20, 0.0037445, 2.80767, 
  0.0891022, 7.46372}, {21, 0.00366125, 2.85969, 0.0685708, 
  7.63264}, {22, 0.00358362, 2.90781, 0.0439095, 7.80201}, {23, 
  0.00353606, 2.93743, 0.0254055, 7.91445}, {24, 0.00350441, 2.9569, 
  0.0112019, 7.99332}, {25, 0.00348267, 2.96992, 4.2709*10^-28, 
  8.05004}, {26, 0.00350619, 2.95655, 0.0140871, 7.98594}, {27, 
  0.00354397, 2.9359, 0.0380519, 7.88204}, {28, 0.0036054, 2.90368, 
  0.077481, 7.71557}, {29, 0.00371579, 2.84915, 0.145356, 
  7.43302}, {30, 0.00384706, 2.78696, 0.22453, 7.10949}, {31, 
  0.00402225, 2.70695, 0.319264, 6.71886}, {32, 0.00425262, 2.60492, 
  0.42526, 6.26836}, {33, 0.00451347, 2.4927, 0.533519, 5.80028}, {34,
   0.00484984, 2.35888, 0.635259, 5.31261}, {35, 0.0052487, 2.21331, 
  0.726175, 4.82797}, {36, 0.00569123, 2.06324, 0.807586, 
  4.35526}, {37, 0.00625698, 1.90488, 0.858761, 3.92207}, {38, 
  0.00689091, 1.74683, 0.894649, 3.51698}, {39, 0.00759815, 1.59081, 
  0.915479, 3.14207}, {40, 0.00847396, 1.44051, 0.907596, 
  2.82513}, {41, 0.00943069, 1.29475, 0.890287, 2.53427}, {42, 
  0.0105185, 1.15519, 0.860229, 2.27889}, {43, 0.0117991, 1.02388, 
  0.81632, 2.06547}, {44, 0.0131859, 0.897942, 0.767916, 
  1.87227}, {45, 0.0147797, 0.780792, 0.713042, 1.70999}, {46, 
  0.0165753, 0.670983, 0.65441, 1.57258}, {47, 0.0184995, 0.565447, 
  0.594737, 1.44957}, {48, 0.0207039, 0.467657, 0.533712, 
  1.35086}, {49, 0.0230828, 0.374668, 0.47279, 1.26641}, {50, 
  0.025591, 0.285255, 0.412327, 1.1928}, {51, 0.0283735, 0.201725, 
  0.353629, 1.13931}, {52, 0.0312372, 0.119185, 0.295722, 
  1.09523}, {53, 0.0341712, 0.0377658, 0.238978, 1.06272}, {54, 
  0.0370919, -0.0411159, 0.184837, 1.04753}, {55, 0.03991, -0.118284, 
  0.132156, 1.04359}, {56, 0.0424219, -0.189196, 0.0842067, 
  1.05721}, {57, 0.0443678, -0.245829, 0.0451427, 1.09405}, {58, 
  0.0458307, -0.287877, 0.0134487, 1.15053}, {59, 
  0.0461722, -0.273939, 0.00724523, 1.25192}, {60, 0.04547, -0.189799,
   0.029489, 1.40789}, {61, 0.0439536, -0.040825, 0.0760268, 
  1.61787}, {62, 0.0410509, 0.287135, 0.188407, 1.98092}, {63, 
  0.0374884, 0.737128, 0.339519, 2.48104}, {64, 0.0334165, 1.32035, 
  0.529929, 3.15253}, {65, 0.0292259, 2.16715, 0.792678, 
  4.24807}, {66, 0.0249774, 3.20952, 1.09423, 5.70677}, {67, 
  0.0209618, 4.54328, 1.4547, 7.76466}, {68, 0.0175535, 6.37734, 
  1.90226, 10.9599}, {69, 0.0142979, 8.71509, 2.3962, 15.3082}, {70, 
  0.0116484, 11.9196, 2.96614, 21.8363}, {71, 0.00952234, 16.4455, 
  3.46263, 31.8198}, {72, 0.00756156, 22.4422, 3.69173, 45.7099}, {73,
   0.00637376, 29.2974, 3.10612, 62.8753}, {74, 0.00557852, 35.9338, 
  1.7877, 80.5131}, {75, 0.0050232, 41.7985, 8.59236*10^-27, 
  96.93}, {76, 0.00564134, 35.4285, 2.17511, 78.8748}, {77, 
  0.00664996, 27.396, 4.4568, 56.9122}, {78, 0.00830127, 18.7827, 
  5.93387, 34.9235}, {79, 0.0112518, 12.1619, 5.34133, 20.6996}, {80, 
  0.0147477, 7.27342, 4.38667, 11.0649}, {81, 0.0192714, 4.31069, 
  3.28923, 6.07815}, {82, 0.0249166, 2.64861, 2.36017, 3.78892}, {83, 
  0.0310646, 1.44104, 1.61259, 2.25868}, {84, 0.038089, 0.763281, 
  1.11354, 1.51843}, {85, 0.0455155, 0.323334, 0.756884, 
  1.08172}, {86, 0.0530392, -0.00833097, 0.480004, 0.764547}, {87, 
  0.0602388, -0.191606, 0.314908, 0.599}, {88, 0.0669456, -0.322307, 
  0.19112, 0.476188}, {89, 0.0729913, -0.407595, 0.101166, 
  0.385506}, {90, 0.0773187, -0.422702, 0.0563086, 0.338125}, {91, 
  0.0808823, -0.415833, 0.0252911, 0.301559}, {92, 
  0.0833385, -0.387366, 0.00888385, 0.276938}, {93, 
  0.0845245, -0.347873, 0.00355736, 0.262038}, {94, 
  0.085323, -0.310296, 0.000716217, 0.249179}, {95, 
  0.0854916, -0.278922, 0.00021299, 0.239806}, {96, 
  0.0853257, -0.253975, 0.000358958, 0.232963}, {97, 
  0.0851545, -0.232974, 0.000267074, 0.227071}, {98, 
  0.0848481, -0.218693, 0.000354803, 0.223956}, {99, 
  0.084646, -0.209427, 0.000303089, 0.222006}, {100, 
  0.0846189, -0.204535, 3.2539*10^-31, 0.220639}, {101, 
  0.084646, -0.209427, 0.000303089, 0.222006}, {102, 
  0.0848481, -0.218693, 0.000354803, 0.223956}, {103, 
  0.0851545, -0.232974, 0.000267074, 0.227071}, {104, 
  0.0853257, -0.253975, 0.000358958, 0.232963}, {105, 
  0.0854916, -0.278922, 0.00021299, 0.239806}, {106, 
  0.085323, -0.310296, 0.000716217, 0.249179}, {107, 
  0.0845245, -0.347873, 0.00355736, 0.262038}, {108, 
  0.0833385, -0.387366, 0.00888385, 0.276938}, {109, 
  0.0808823, -0.415833, 0.0252911, 0.301559}, {110, 
  0.0773187, -0.422702, 0.0563086, 0.338125}, {111, 
  0.0729913, -0.407595, 0.101166, 0.385506}, {112, 
  0.0669456, -0.322307, 0.19112, 0.476188}, {113, 
  0.0602388, -0.191606, 0.314908, 0.599}, {114, 
  0.0530392, -0.00833097, 0.480004, 0.764547}, {115, 0.0455155, 
  0.323334, 0.756884, 1.08172}, {116, 0.038089, 0.763281, 1.11354, 
  1.51843}, {117, 0.0310646, 1.44104, 1.61259, 2.25868}, {118, 
  0.0249166, 2.64861, 2.36017, 3.78892}, {119, 0.0192714, 4.31069, 
  3.28923, 6.07815}, {120, 0.0147477, 7.27342, 4.38667, 
  11.0649}, {121, 0.0112518, 12.1619, 5.34133, 20.6996}, {122, 
  0.00830127, 18.7827, 5.93387, 34.9235}, {123, 0.00664996, 27.396, 
  4.4568, 56.9122}, {124, 0.00564134, 35.4285, 2.17511, 
  78.8748}, {125, 0.0050232, 41.7985, 5.2584*10^-27, 96.93}, {126, 
  0.00557852, 35.9338, 1.7877, 80.5131}, {127, 0.00637376, 29.2974, 
  3.10612, 62.8753}, {128, 0.00756156, 22.4422, 3.69173, 
  45.7099}, {129, 0.00952234, 16.4455, 3.46263, 31.8198}, {130, 
  0.0116484, 11.9196, 2.96614, 21.8363}, {131, 0.0142979, 8.71509, 
  2.3962, 15.3082}, {132, 0.0175535, 6.37734, 1.90226, 10.9599}, {133,
   0.0209618, 4.54328, 1.4547, 7.76466}, {134, 0.0249774, 3.20952, 
  1.09423, 5.70677}, {135, 0.0292259, 2.16715, 0.792678, 
  4.24807}, {136, 0.0334165, 1.32035, 0.529929, 3.15253}, {137, 
  0.0374884, 0.737128, 0.339519, 2.48104}, {138, 0.0410509, 0.287135, 
  0.188407, 1.98092}, {139, 0.0439536, -0.040825, 0.0760268, 
  1.61787}, {140, 0.04547, -0.189799, 0.029489, 1.40789}, {141, 
  0.0461722, -0.273939, 0.00724523, 1.25192}, {142, 
  0.0458307, -0.287877, 0.0134487, 1.15053}, {143, 
  0.0443678, -0.245829, 0.0451427, 1.09405}, {144, 
  0.0424219, -0.189196, 0.0842067, 1.05721}, {145, 0.03991, -0.118284,
   0.132156, 1.04359}, {146, 0.0370919, -0.0411159, 0.184837, 
  1.04753}, {147, 0.0341712, 0.0377658, 0.238978, 1.06272}, {148, 
  0.0312372, 0.119185, 0.295722, 1.09523}, {149, 0.0283735, 0.201725, 
  0.353629, 1.13931}, {150, 0.025591, 0.285255, 0.412327, 
  1.1928}, {151, 0.0230828, 0.374668, 0.47279, 1.26641}, {152, 
  0.0207039, 0.467657, 0.533712, 1.35086}, {153, 0.0184995, 0.565447, 
  0.594737, 1.44957}, {154, 0.0165753, 0.670983, 0.65441, 
  1.57258}, {155, 0.0147797, 0.780792, 0.713042, 1.70999}, {156, 
  0.0131859, 0.897942, 0.767916, 1.87227}, {157, 0.0117991, 1.02388, 
  0.81632, 2.06547}, {158, 0.0105185, 1.15519, 0.860229, 
  2.27889}, {159, 0.00943069, 1.29475, 0.890287, 2.53427}, {160, 
  0.00847396, 1.44051, 0.907596, 2.82513}, {161, 0.00759815, 1.59081, 
  0.915479, 3.14207}, {162, 0.00689091, 1.74683, 0.894649, 
  3.51698}, {163, 0.00625698, 1.90488, 0.858761, 3.92207}, {164, 
  0.00569123, 2.06324, 0.807586, 4.35526}, {165, 0.0052487, 2.21331, 
  0.726175, 4.82797}, {166, 0.00484984, 2.35888, 0.635259, 
  5.31261}, {167, 0.00451347, 2.4927, 0.533519, 5.80028}, {168, 
  0.00425262, 2.60492, 0.42526, 6.26836}, {169, 0.00402225, 2.70695, 
  0.319264, 6.71886}, {170, 0.00384706, 2.78696, 0.22453, 
  7.10949}, {171, 0.00371579, 2.84915, 0.145356, 7.43302}, {172, 
  0.0036054, 2.90368, 0.077481, 7.71557}, {173, 0.00354397, 2.9359, 
  0.0380519, 7.88204}, {174, 0.00350619, 2.95655, 0.0140871, 
  7.98594}, {175, 0.00348267, 2.96992, 4.34023*10^-27, 8.05004}, {176,
   0.00350441, 2.9569, 0.0112019, 7.99332}, {177, 0.00353606, 2.93743,
   0.0254055, 7.91445}, {178, 0.00358362, 2.90781, 0.0439095, 
  7.80201}, {179, 0.00366125, 2.85969, 0.0685708, 7.63264}, {180, 
  0.0037445, 2.80767, 0.0891022, 7.46372}, {181, 0.0038446, 2.74659, 
  0.107359, 7.27855}, {182, 0.003962, 2.67731, 0.122165, 
  7.08088}, {183, 0.00408066, 2.60798, 0.130038, 6.89764}, {184, 
  0.00421573, 2.53408, 0.13467, 6.70861}, {185, 0.00435635, 2.46022, 
  0.134399, 6.52873}, {186, 0.00449348, 2.3895, 0.12767, 
  6.36945}, {187, 0.00464483, 2.31891, 0.12169, 6.20612}, {188, 
  0.00479085, 2.25265, 0.111276, 6.06199}, {189, 0.00493048, 2.19114, 
  0.0969574, 5.937}, {190, 0.00507624, 2.13333, 0.0868532, 
  5.80991}, {191, 0.00520924, 2.08121, 0.0728039, 5.70511}, {192, 
  0.00533414, 2.03443, 0.0587529, 5.61315}, {193, 0.005454, 1.99256, 
  0.0488175, 5.52469}, {194, 0.00555664, 1.95654, 0.0357567, 
  5.4579}, {195, 0.0056491, 1.92576, 0.026371, 5.3971}, {196, 
  0.00572788, 1.90041, 0.0195179, 5.34518}, {197, 0.00578611, 1.88105,
   0.00995626, 5.31438}, {198, 0.00583292, 1.86694, 0.00737286, 
  5.28264}, {199, 0.00586038, 1.85857, 0.00496208, 5.26553}, {200, 
  0.00586554, 1.85613, 4.76551*10^-28, 5.26926}}
```

**EDIT**

What @kglr had given me below was not working when I cut and paste into mathematica. Came out with the error "Array {1.956539662351, 0.03575672615657, 5.457899268063} has the wrong dimensions for a graphics coordinate list." But here is what I put that worked instead:

```
Si3d = Show[
   ListPointPlot3D[Sidata1[[1 ;; 59, 3 ;; 5]], PlotStyle -> {Red}, 
    PlotRange -> All],
   ListPointPlot3D[Sidata1[[60 ;; 89, 3 ;; 5]], PlotStyle -> {Gray}, 
    PlotRange -> All],
   ListPointPlot3D[Sidata1[[90 ;; 110, 3 ;; 5]], PlotStyle -> {Red}, 
    PlotRange -> All],
   ListPointPlot3D[Sidata1[[111 ;; 141, 3 ;; 5]], PlotStyle -> {Gray},
     PlotRange -> All],
   ListPointPlot3D[Sidata1[[142 ;; 201, 3 ;; 5]], PlotStyle -> {Red}, 
    PlotRange -> All], 
   AxesLabel -> {"q", "s2", "alpha"}, LabelStyle -> {16}, PlotLabel -> None, 
   ViewPoint -> {.5, -2, 1}, AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, 16], 
   BoxStyle -> Directive[Black], TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 16], 
   AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {-1, -1}}, ImageSize -> Large] /. 
  Point -> ({AbsoluteThickness[3], Line@#} &)
```

However, for a plot where I zoom in on my data, The lines are no longer connected. First picture is what it looks like with the thin line but data is connected. Second picture is with the thick line but data no longer connected. Only thing that changes me replacing "Line" with "({AbsoluteThickness[3], Line@#} &)" :

```
Si3dsection = Show[Si3d, PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 7}, {0, 3}, {0, 10}}, 
  AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {1, -1}}, 
  ViewPoint -> {-1, -2.5, 1}]
```

[image]

[image]

**EDIT #2**
Actually, I think I figured out my second problem, they weren't connecting anymore because when I increased the line thickness, some parts of the line went outside the bounds of my box so that section of data just was not showing up anymore, all I had to do was expand my plot range. Sorry for the headache (at least I had one anyway) but thank you all for your help!

Comment: Try this instead: `expr /. Point[args__] :> {Thickness[0.1], Line[args]}` and report back.

Comment: Why not put the line thickness in the `PlotStyle` to begin with?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I tried putting in PlotStyle -> Thickness[3], but it did not change the line thickness at all. Do you know why?

Comment: Where did you put it? It has to go inside each `ListPointPlot3D`, combined with each color. (BTW, `Thickness[t]` sets the thickness relative to the image width. So `Thickness[3]` would set the thickness to be three times the width of the image -- each line would would fill the image.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.** Add the desired thickness directive in `PlotStyle` in `ListPointPlot3D`:

```
ListPointPlot3D[TakeList[Sidata1[[All, 3 ;; 5]], {59, 30, 21, 31, 60}], 
  PlotStyle -> (Directive[AbsoluteThickness[3], #] & /@ {Red, Gray, Red, Gray, Red}), 
  PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"q", "s2", "alpha"}, LabelStyle -> {16}, 
  PlotLabel -> None, ViewPoint -> {.5, -2, 1}, 
  AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, 16], BoxStyle -> Directive[Black], 
  TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 16], 
  AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {-1, -1}}, ImageSize -> Large] /. 
 Point -> Line
```

[image]

**2.** Change the replacement rule as suggested by @J.M. to, say,  `Point -> ({AbsoluteThickness[3], Line @ #} &)`:

```
ListPointPlot3D[TakeList[Sidata1[[All, 3 ;; 5]], {59, 30, 21, 31, 60}], 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Gray, Red, Gray, Red}, 
  PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"q", "s2", "alpha"}, 
  LabelStyle -> {16}, PlotLabel -> None, ViewPoint -> {.5, -2, 1}, 
  AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, 16], BoxStyle -> Directive[Black], 
  TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 16], 
  AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {-1, -1}}, ImageSize -> Large] /. 
 Point -> ({AbsoluteThickness[3], Line@#} &)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! You always answer my questions so quickly. I appreciate it!

Comment: So I found that when I cut and paste your code into mathematica, it comes up with this error: `Array {1.956539662351, 0.03575672615657, 5.457899268063} has the wrong dimensions for a graphics coordinate list.` I see that you simplified how to choose what data is red and gray but if it worked for you I don't see why it doesn't for me? So instead what I did is I just added `({AbsoluteThickness[3], Line@#} &)` to what I already instead of "Line" and it worked. BUT now a zoomed in plot is cutting out regions of my line? It should all be connected. I'll edit above to show you what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to add the `Thickness[]` spec to each plot, you can use plot themes.  See [Is it possible to define a new PlotTheme?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54545/is-it-possible-to-define-a-new-plottheme/54637#54637) (Mr.Wizard's answer) for the source of this idea:

```
System`PlotThemeDump`resolvePlotTheme["myThickness", 
  "ListPointPlot3D"] := 
 Themes`SetWeight[{"DefaultThickness" -> {Thickness[0.01]}}, 
  System`PlotThemeDump`$ComponentWeight]

Block[{$PlotTheme = {"Default", "myThickness"}},
 Show[ListPointPlot3D[Sidata1[[1 ;; 59, 3 ;; 5]], PlotStyle -> {Red}, 
    PlotRange -> All], 
   ListPointPlot3D[Sidata1[[60 ;; 89, 3 ;; 5]], PlotStyle -> {Gray}, 
    PlotRange -> All], 
   ListPointPlot3D[Sidata1[[90 ;; 110, 3 ;; 5]], PlotStyle -> {Red}, 
    PlotRange -> All], 
   ListPointPlot3D[Sidata1[[111 ;; 141, 3 ;; 5]], PlotStyle -> {Gray},
     PlotRange -> All], 
   ListPointPlot3D[Sidata1[[142 ;; 201, 3 ;; 5]], PlotStyle -> {Red}, 
    PlotRange -> All], AxesLabel -> {"q", "s2", "alpha"}, 
   LabelStyle -> {16}, PlotLabel -> None, ViewPoint -> {.5, -2, 1}, 
   AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, 16], BoxStyle -> Directive[Black], 
   TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 16], 
   AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {-1, -1}}, ImageSize -> Large] /. 
  Point -> Line
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how to fix the problem I listed in my "EDIT" section above? At a certain line thickness, my plot no longer stays all connected, how do I keep them connected?

Comment: @btilson I'm not sure what you want. The three red lines are disconnected because they are constructed from three data sets. To join the lines, join the data set: `Show[
  ListPointPlot3D[
   Join[
    Sidata1[[1 ;; 59, 3 ;; 5]],
    Sidata1[[90 ;; 110, 3 ;; 5]],
    Sidata1[[142 ;; 201, 3 ;; 5]]
    ], PlotStyle -> {Red}, PlotRange -> All]
  ] /. Point -> Line` -- that joins all three.  Perhaps you want to join only two of them and keep the third one separate. To get the right ends to line up, you sometimes have to reverse one of them (like `Join[d1, Reverse@d2]`).

Comment: @btilson If you zoom in far enough in your original (thin line) plot, they are not connected:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/fcRmo.png

Comment: With what you are saying with the `Join` command, what if you want some of data points to be red and the others gray? Like what if I wanted data points 90 - 110 gray instead of red?

Comment: Actually, I think I figured out the problem, they weren't connecting anymore because when I increased the line thickness, some parts of the line went outside the bounds of my box so that section of data just was not showing up anymore, all I had to do was expand my plot range. Sorry for the headache (at least I had one anyway) but thank you for your help!